# Does using custom fonts in my iOS app impact the app size?

Tags: ios, fonts

1. I have to use a custom font in my app, NotoSans, and it takes up 1.6 MB. If I use this font instead of the default font on iOS, will that impact the app size?
2. What if I use San Francisco (iOS System font for EN) and Hiragino Sans (iOS System font for JP)? Will these fonts impact the size of the app in any way?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, different font files should be included in the app bundle, so they will make your app size larger.
2. No, since they are included in iOS.